# Dual monitor with 2x DVI connectors not working

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I am trying to connect 2 monitors to my Radeon HD 6950 (it has 2 DVI connectors and 1 HDMI connector). But only one DVI connector works. With the other one I don't get any signal.

Is my videocard broken or do I have to configure something?

Also if I try to connect my 1080p 144hz monitor using HDMI then I get a smaller screen (still 1920x1080 of resolution but 60hz refresh rate) with black border around the windows desktop.

Can anyone show me a path to follow because I do not know these things well.

Comment: Have you tried swapping the monitors between the 2 dvi ports to make sure both monitors work? Also try swapping cables as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 7 or Windows 8/8.1, then you should try pressing the Windows Key and P at the same time. This should call up a four-paneled window that says "Computer Only," "Duplicate," "Extend," and "Projector Only." Using either the mouse or the arrow keys and Enter, select the Extend option. That should fire up the other monitor. Now, if they're not arranged properly (e.g, you have to move the mouse to the left side of the monitor to get it to go to the screen on the right), right click on your Desktop and select Screen Resolution. From there, you should see a picture of your two monitors. Click and drag one of them to reposition it or adjust resolution as needed.